# Orange material in grout lines - need help to identify

Tags: shower, tile, floor, grout

Having recently moved into a new (resale) house, I looked closely at the grout lines on one of the tiled shower floors and noticed many small gaps in the grout lines with an unidentified orange material in the gaps. I've attached a picture.

Obviously this grout is not in good condition and needs to be replaced; however, does anyone know what the orange material in the grout lines is? It appears to be coming from underneath and is raised into the gaps between the tiles, so occupies some of the cavity where the grout would normally go.

Thanks for any suggestions.

[image: Grout lines containing unidentified orange material]

Comment: could be a heated floor? Could also be that someone placed spacers during the tiling process and left them in. Are they hard or soft feeling?

Comment: Not sure about heated floor - if it is, there's no obvious way to control it. They are hard feeling - they didn't give at all when prodded.

Comment: y guess then, would be that they left the tile spacers in there when the tile was laid. Unless someone else has an idea, that would be my guess. Most of the spacers I have seen and I have used, are a cross type, plastic/silicone, that you place standing up, between tiles, so that once the tile has set, before you grout, you go along and pull them up. One end goes between the tiles, the horizontal parts rest on the tile, and the other piece points up so you can grab it. Some come in 2 different sizes on each cross, others are one size on all 4 sides.

Comment: Not enough grout installed.  Or mixed wrong.  And membrane  showing.

Comment: I don’t see grout. I only see the mortar that the tiles were set in.

Comment: Could be spacers...

Comment: There's no grout.  Either it was improperly installed, never set, and all washed down the drain or the tile job was never finished in the first place.  This is the shower floor, so if the shower was being used water will have soaked through those holes and flooded the ditra underneath.  Given it's ditra and assuming there's a proper amount of mortar underneath the water should not have been able to travel far, but there may still be water damage underneath.

Comment: Is that grout, or caulk?

Comment: Tic-tac used as spacers? :-)

Answer (score 20):

Looks like schluter ditra waterproofing membrane. [image]

Amazon describes it:

> This universal underlayment specifically designed for ceramic and stone tile eliminates the main cause of cracking in your tile installation. Tile and stone are rigid materials and are, therefore, sensitive to stresses originating in the sub floor. This uncoupling membrane allows independent movement between the sub floor and the finished surface, thereby neutralizing these stresses. Exclusively designed for ceramic and stone tile Waterproofs and allows moisture in the substrate to evaporate Replaces backerboard or a second layer of plywood 1/8 in. thick makes transitioning to other surfaces simple Ideal for interior and exterior tile and stone installations Easy to install

Below is an image of tile being installed over ditra using thinset mortar. This is as far as your installation progressed. Your floor was not grouted after the tiles were set.
[image]
I recommend scrubbing and rinsing thoroughly using a wet vac to remove water. Allow floor to dry well then grout with appropriate product.

Comment: This^^^. Two notes: don't cut it when re-grouting. And Ditra is generally associated with better quality installs, so you've got that going for you.

Comment: Thanks all - would you expect Ditra to occupy space **between** the tiles? It looks like it would only be underneath but I don’t have much experience in this area.

Comment: @mattbg Looks almost like the tile was installed with thinset mortar over ditra and never grouted.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on here, but that's not normal looking grout, and it's not normal looking thinset either.  Really looks like Ditra, but looks like there is no grout like Kris said.

Comment: @mattbg If you want to grout between tiles, you leave gaps between them so there is a space to fill properly with grout. (When you are laying the tiles, you use spacers to get equal sized gaps between them, and remove the spacers before the tile cement sets). I guess the grout has cracked away and the backing membrane is showing through the holes.

Comment: @alephzero  there is no grout between his tiles

Comment: I was going to suggest tile spacers or the backing to hold multiple tiles together for quicker installation (like on smaller tiles), but this seems like a much more likely answer.

Comment: @Kris: could you add "there is no grout between his tiles" to your answer?

Comment: Thanks all - as per your suggestions I am going to clean and dry the area and then grout. I'm completely puzzled about why this area would not have been grouted at all to begin with - it looks like it has seen regular use over many years.